# Confused by has_many and belongs_to associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I'm a little bit confused here. I have 2 models:
User
Ticket

- A Ticket belongs to one User as a "reporter".
- A Ticket belongs to one User as "assigned".
- A User has many Tickets (twice ?)

So here what I've got:

```
# Table name: tickets
#
#  id             :integer         not null, primary key
#  label          :string(255)
#  content        :text
#  reported_by_id :integer
#  assigned_to_id :integer
#  created_at     :datetime
#  updated_at     :datetime
#
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :reported_by, :class_name => 'User'
  belongs_to :assigned_to, :class_name => 'User'
end

# Table name: users
#
#  id         :integer         not null, primary key
#  login      :string(255)
#  password   :string(255)
#  created_at :datetime
#  updated_at :datetime
#
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tickets, :class_name => 'Ticket', :foreign_key => 'reported_by_id'
  has_many :tickets, :class_name => 'Ticket', :foreign_key => 'assigned_to_id'
end
```

I would like to do "aUser.tickets" and get all user's tickets that he reported.

Any help ?
Thx !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should differentiate the names of your has_many in your User model:

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :reported_by_tickets, :class_name => 'Ticket', :foreign_key => 'reported_by_id'
   has_many :assigned_to_tickets, :class_name => 'Ticket', :foreign_key => 'assigned_to_id'
 end
```

Now call

```
 @user.reported_by_tickets
 @user.assigned_to_tickets
```

Otherwise, your code looks right on target.

Comment: Actually, the "build" command is not working properly. Doing aUser.reported_by_tickets.build() works but is not setting the "reported_by_id" field. Any idea ?

Comment: Hmm, this definitely should work correctly-- is there anything in your model that would prevent this, such as attr_accessible?

Comment: I just reproduced this precise scenario and everything is working for me, including reported_by_id.  Can you possibly include more code that could be relevant?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to different properties for two different relations and a third method that combines the two.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reported_tickets, :class_name => 'Ticket', :foreign_key => 'reported_by_id'
  has_many :assigned_tickets, :class_name => 'Ticket', :foreign_key => 'assigned_to_id'

  def tickets
    reported_tickets + assigned_tickets
  end
end
```